# Problem with mixins in a MooseX::NonMoose class

Tags: perl, moose, mixins, cgiapp, mop

Consider the following:

```
package MyApp::CGI;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use Data::Dumper;

extends 'CGI::Application';

BEGIN { 
    print "begin isa = " . Dumper \@MyApp::CGI::ISA;
};

print "runtime isa = " . Dumper \@MyApp::CGI::ISA;

...
```

The output when this compiles is:

```
begin isa = $VAR1 = [
          'Moose::Object'
        ];
runtime isa = $VAR1 = [
          'CGI::Application',
          'Moose::Object'
        ];
```

Why do I care? Because when I try to `use` a CGI::Application::Plugin::* class, it expects me to be inheriting from `CGI::Application` at compile-time already. The plugin class tries to call `add_callback` as a class method on my class, but can't, because my `@ISA` isn't set up yet.

What's the best way to solve this? Would tweaking `@ISA` manually in a `BEGIN` block interfere with `MooseX::NonMoose`?

**Edit**

The following appears to work, but I find it offensive:

```
package MyApp::CGI;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;

use base 'CGI::Application';
extends 'CGI::Application';
```

I don't know enough (or anything, really) about Moose internals to know if this is a good idea.

Comment: (Worth noting that "use" as a synonym for BEGIN is a common antipattern.  See also: "use ok ...")

Comment: jrockway: that should be an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't find `use base 'CGI::Application'; extends 'CGI::Application';` to be terribly ghastly because it does precisely what you need:

- At compile-time, `@ISA` contains `'CGI::Application'`, which exactly satisfies the usage requirements of CGI::Application::Plugin::*
- At runtime, your class is a [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) descendant of [CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI-Application/), with all the ensuing benefits (being able to design the composition of your class with Moosey meta goodness). It's only after the `extends 'CGI::Application'` line is encountered that any work is done (i.e methods are called on your class) that rely on the work done by the `extends` statement: that your class descends from `Moose::Object` and you have a meta-class installed.

That said, jrockway's solution should also work:

```
BEGIN { extends 'CGI::Application' }
```

...where you get all the Moosey meta goodness just a little ahead of schedule from when you need it, and it shouldn't be *too* ahead of schedule, provided you already called `use Moose` and `use MooseX::NonMoose` in order to define `extends`.

<sub>(Addendum: Now I'm pondering the complilational complexities of creating the ability to force the parsing of a keyword at compile-time that are parsed immediately such as if they were wrapped in a `BEGIN` block. e.g. something like if Moose.pm declared `use compiletime qw(extends)`. It would be a nice piece of syntactic sugar for sure.)</sub>

Comment: Using a `BEGIN` block works. I'd give the ++ to jrockaway but he didn't post it in an answer. :)

Comment: Ether:  Devel::BeginLift does that.